# How to read json data and filter it from a dataframe where one column has json data type

Tags: python, json, database, pandas, dataframe

I have two tables:

1. Customer
   [image]
2. Account
   [image]

I created these table in SQLite and import it to Pyhton through following code

```
-- Python Pandas code
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
-- Creating connection
cnx = sqlite3.connect('testdatabase.db')

Customer = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM Customer", cnx)
Account = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM Account", cnx)
```

I want to fetch all state names and total of account balance for the users belonging to those states.
My expected output would be the following table:

[image]

One way I can solve this problem is that

```
data = cnx.execute("SELECT JSON_VALUE(c.address, '$.state') AS State,
                    SUM(a.account_balance) AS Account_balance
                    FROM Customer c 
                    INNER JOIN Account a ON c.id = a.user_id
                    WHERE JSON_VALUE(c.address, '$.state') IS NOT NULL
                    GROUP BY JSON_VALUE(c.address, '$.state')")
 for row in data:
   print "State = ", row[0]
   print "Account_balance = ", row[1], "\n"
cnx.close()
```

But I don't want to use this approach instead I want to solve this using pandas library and the dataframe which I create above.
Kindly suggest me with the concept and solutions for performing this operation.

Comment: Can you try: ```Address, Balance = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT Address, Account_balance FROM Customer, Account where Customer.id = Account.User_id", cnx)```

Then you can easily get the State from Address.

Comment: @pagalprogrammer I just want name of states not the whole address. I have also mentioned the desired output.

Comment: As i said earlier, you can access the state from Address variable. If you have stored the address as a string, you can first convert it to JSON using json library or if it is json then you can access it like ```State = Address['state']```